# How do you share a global resource between activities in windows workflow foundation 4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'd like to create a set of custom activities that do work on a shared resource (like a file).  These custom activities will be used in a number of workflows, each of which will have this shared resource in common.  My goal is to make creating these workflows as simple as possible since each is just a rearrangement of a few basic activities.

I've managed to use an InArgument and pass this resource to each activity but since this is tedious I was wondering how I might simplify it so that the argument wouldn't be necessary.

Also, would it be possible to initialize this resource in one place so that all workflows could assume it already exists?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can explore the use of Workflow Extensions if you like. Basically you leverage the "Service Locator" pattern.

Define a class that knows how to access/modify this file that you have. Say this class called ResourceLocator implements a IResourceLocator interface. Then when you create your workflow host do this

```
class ServiceLocator:IServiceLocator
{

public FileStream GetFile(string path){
}

}
```

//initiate WF host here
    host.Extensions.Add(()=>{new ResourceLocator();});

Then from within your custom activities you can do

```
context.GetExtension<IResourceLocator>().GetFile(pathToFile);
```

Basically this Extension becomes your means to share common code between workflows. You can split it out in a different assembly and share it between different workflow projects.

Comment: The extension system in WF4 already is a "service locator" type pattern (although a little bit better, as activities can declare exactly what services they require to exist within CacheMetadata).  Therefore there is no need adding a service locator within a service locator.  He should create an extension that directly provides the service he needs and his activities should always require the extension.

Comment: That IMHO will lead to two problems that tend to go out of out hand as WF grows. The first one being that each activity's number of arguments increase which leads to a number of problems in writing/maintaining unit test cases. The second is that now every unit test case or your WF host must account for and provide for all these different extensions. Having a centralized service locator bypasses these. You can also follow Interface Segregation and have your central service locator implement different interfaces that know how to locate a service. Makes it easier to mock up stubs  for unit tests.

Comment: There is a centralized service locator--`context.GetExtension<T>`.  And if your activities are getting too big you're probably doing it wrong.  They are supposed to be composed, not monolithic.  In your unit tests, you have to mock your extensions out *anyhow*, so your service locator is just another mock you have to make.  The service locator pattern has already been surpassed by much better patterns, namely IoC/DI.  Its a dinosaur.  Let is be oil.

Comment: Say I had a resource that my custom activities act on called `MyResource`.  This resource has different initialization arguments for each workflow.  So what I've tried was I created a class called `MyResourceContext` that has `MyResource` as a property then I add this context to the extensions.  I also created a custom activity that takes arguments so I can initialize the resource by first calling `GetExtension()` to get `MyResourceContext` and then initializing the `MyResource` property with the activity's arguments.  The code works, but is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: By the way I'll accept this answer since it helped me get what I wanted but if anyone has input on my comment above I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: @Will you have completely lost the point. My case was for those activities which aren't "monolithic" but for workflows where there are simply too many external dependencies to manage. If you have worked on true enterprise scale workflows you would appreciate where I am coming from. And if you do some research into this issue, you will find that for workflows DI and IoC "do not work" and that for WFs, Service Locator is indeed the best pattern.

Comment: To complete this discussion let me also point out that context.GetExtension<T> is the correct pattern to use. What you are missing is the correct plumbing that needs to happen to use it "effectively". My solution offloads the task of discovering dependencies to a Service Locator Component(or call JungleBook for all I care) which is then plumbed back into the native WF service locator pattern.

Comment: @Nikhil: lol, sure thing there Mr. Enterprise.  I've only been using WF4 since its first beta.  Methinks you're hiding your design flaws behind your service locator--"too many external dependencies to manage", eh?  I'd also love to see some citations for *workflows DI and IoC "do not work"*.

Comment: Well I have been running since I was 6 months old but that doesn't mean I can beat Ussain Bolt today in 100m Sprint. I perhaps was a bit overzealous when I said they "do not work". I should have stated that while you can "Make them work", the concepts of WF are best served using service locators.